# Can apps update without Google account?

Tags: google-play-store, settings, google-account, application-autoupdate

Scenario:
- No Google account is attached to the phone
- No apps have been installed beside ones that where already on the phone (even after a factory reset)

Questions: 
- Is it possible to let the apps update without entering any Google account?
- Can apps update in the background when no Google Account has been entered into the phone?

I could not find this information in the FAQ.

Comment: Related: [Why do I need a Gmail account to use Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21149/why-do-i-need-a-gmail-account-to-use-android)

Answer (score 2):

**No Google Account means no Play store.**

And one thing is clear, if you don't sign in with Google account then it will not allow you to download or update any application from/to play store.

Answer (score 1):

There are app stores that allow to update apps without a Google account. For example, 
[Yalp store](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/) allows to:

> download apps
>   directly from Google Play Store as apk files . It can search for updates of installed apps and lets you
>   search for other apps. Yalp saves downloaded apks to your default download folder. Other features include browsing categories, viewing and leaving reviews, black/whitelisting apps for updates, filtering apps by being free/paid and containing/not containing ads.

When using it, you don't need a Google account, while the apps are downloaded for you directly from Google Play Store.

There are stores such as [Aurora](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.aurora.store/) and many others listed on our wiki that can be used to accomplish what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible... You need a google account to download any app and to do any kind of operation on the apps.

Answer (score 0):

You want be able to access Google Play.  So none of the normal automatic updating will work.  Some apps may be avalible from other sources in which case you may be able to update them manually it will be an app by app thing.

Answer (score 0):

Preloaded apps will soon be able to update even without logging in.

See this [article](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/02/15/google-plans-to-let-preloaded-apps-update-via-google-play-even-if-you-dont-log-in/):

> Google is contacting developers who have apps preloaded on phones to give them a friendly heads up on an upcoming change. In the coming months, Google plans to begin testing a feature that allows preloaded apps to update via the Play Store even if you don't log in. As Google says, this will provide a more consistent app experience for users.

Comment: Did this test ever become permanent?

Comment: Yes, all preloaded apps (and only that) are being updated on my phone just by entering Google Play, no sign up is required.

Comment: I tried to enter Google Play (Android 9) but its homepage just loaded indefinitely until I clicked to log in.

Comment: I am on Marshmallow (6.0), maybe they stopped doing that after.

Comment: Would love it if you or someone else finds a definite reference to that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible,to do it manually you have to download the last apk of the app you want to update from browser, and then install it, and to do it automatically just install Aptoide, download it from browser, and turn on auto update and give to the app root permissions.